# JavaScript in WordPress not loading

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

So I'm trying to get a custom JavaScript file working on my pages that alters element heights on my pages (saves me having to do it as it's different on each page) though it doesn't work.

I've tried adding it through PHP and HTML in the `header.php`, `functions.php`, `footer.php` and even in the actual page itself.

If will load for the very first time, not work, and then when I go set break points and refresh, it doesn't load.

I have the file in the theme's JavaScript folder and the methods I've used to add it are:

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/elementHeight.js"></script> (header and footer)

wp_enqueue_script( 'elementHeight', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/elementHeight.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1' ); (functions)
```

I don't know what's going on. The first time I loaded it in the page, I noticed it actually fetched everything in the file and pasted it within the two `<script>` tags minified but also in `CDATA` tags.

Is there a reason my script isn't loading and/or is there something I'm missing?

EDIT:
I just noticed that the script gets added to the page but the link has `.pagespeed.jm.d-4Yn-ag4z.js` appended to it which is an old cached version though I don't have any caching plugins.
Can someone tell me what's going on?

Comment: This is not the native behavior of Wordpress, I would guess you have a minification plugin that may be breaking it. Have you tried disabling your plugins and/or using a different browser?

Comment: I have disabled all plugins that aren't running so I only have Akismet, Clef, Jetpack, Insert PHP, Google Analytics, GT3 Page Builder, and Varnish HTTP Purge.

Comment: I just noticed that when it does load, it loads before images which shouldn't happen.

Comment: You might try setting the in footer parameter to true on `wp_enqueue_script`, which would load it after the body. You should be using enqueuing for all scripts where possible. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: Doesn't change anything @JeremiahWinsley unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/elementHeight.js'; ?>"></script>
```

Try it that way in only the header or footer.

Depending on the format of `get_template_directory_uri()` you may want to exclude the first `/` in `/js/elementHeight.js`

Which will then be:

```
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/elementHeight.js'; ?>"></script>
```

Comment: I never said I tried it in both... Anyhow, it doesn't work. See http://i.imgur.com/LMuS8No.png

Answer (score -1):

I would use `bloginfo('template_directory')`

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```